# Нужны ли в предложении запятые между прилагательными и перед "преимущественно"?

Tags: прилагательные

Нужны ли в предложении запятые между прилагательными и перед "преимущественно"?

> Выявлены множественные(,) разнокалиберные(,) преимущественно лимфатические
> очаги без четких контуров, размерами до 5 мм.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы записала так: *Выявлены множественные **разнокалиберные, преимущественно лимфатические** очаги без четких контуров, размерами до 5 мм.*

**Пояснение**

Существительные "очаги" имеет пять определений: три согласованных и два несогласованных.

Первое определение обозначает **количество**, а второе и третье имеют **качественное значение**. Их мы будем считать однородными (запятая между ними ставится).

К одному из определений относится наречие "преимущественно".